# How to re-flash stock android OS if I accidentally format the entire storage system using TWRP wipe

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, tablet

I am using the Samsung Galaxy Tab S 8.4 inch , SM-T705 model running on 4.4.2 kitkat stock android.

I was trying to flash a new rom and I went and did a wipe on everything using TWRP custom recovery. It was my stupid mistake and now my tablet is always struck at the loading screen when I restart it. It can still be booted into recovery mode. I need some urgent help dealing with this situation. Can you guys advice on this matter. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

- You can download the stock firmware for your device from [here](http://www.mrcrab.net/stockrom/sm-t705.html).
  Make sure you download the correct version.
- Now you have to download [Odin](http://www.odindownload.com/).
- Now you have to put Samsung Tab S 8.4 LTE
  SM-T705 into download mode using these steps:

  - Turn off Galaxy Tab S 8.4 LTE SM-T705
    carefully.
  - Press your Tab S 8.4 LTE SM-T705
    volume down button and home button
    simultaneously.
  - Press your Tab S 8.4 LTE SM-T705 Power
    button at the same time while pressing its
    Home button and volume down button.
    Press your Tab S 8.4 LTE SM-T705 Power
    button again after viewing a warning
    message to put it into download mode.
- Launch Odin on your PC and connect Tab S
  8.4 LTE SM-T705 with your PC via USB cable.
- You can see a message in the bottom left
  corner of Odin after connecting Tab S 8.4 LTE
  SM-T705 with your PC.
- Now you have to extract the ZIP file of the downloaded firmware on your PC to get a tar.md5 file.
- Once you have successfully extracted the ZIP
  file, you have
  to press “AP” in Odin and choose “.tar.md5″ file.
- Now you have to press the “Start” button in
  Odin after selecting “Auto-reboot” option.
- Now you need to wait until your SM-T705 is
  restarted.
- It should now be running the stock firmware you flashed.

Comment: +1 and glad it worked for OP. @VishnuvardhanKumar please accept this answer as it has helped you and may help others. A note I always add is: before you format/wipe/install ANYTHING via recovery make a [tag:nandroid] backup, then backup the backup onto your PC or somewhere safe. They can be a life saver if you like flashing on your phone regularly, and give you a safety net if all goes wrong!

Comment: @RossC I think you meant to tag LimKianHwee. I was the one who provided the answer.

Comment: @LimKianHwee Is who I meant to tag. Sorry about that! I think my brain has given up for the rest of today! Good answer still though, just a slightly stupid comment underneath it from me!

Comment: @RossC No problem, happens to all of us.